# Accessing an Element in a List

Tags: python, list

I have a list as shown:

```
output = ['item01', 'item02']
part = output[1]
print(part)
```

Is it possible to assign the element to a variable without the quotes without doing a replacement of the character?  If I do the print, the output of part is displayed as:

```
'item02'
```

Comment: Why the quotes should not be displayed?

Comment: Um, this just prints `item02`. Are you sure there's nothing else in your program?

Comment: Mureinik, you are correct, I do not see the single quotes now when I tried it.  Very odd.....

Answer (score 0):

Your `item02` is a string of characters. So, if you assign a Python object say `x` to it, it must be equated to `'item02'` because you have not defined any Python object `item02`.

> If I do the print, the output of part is displayed as: 'item02'

I don't think this is correct. Try it on both Python 2, or Python 3, this code is same

```
>>> x = 'item02'
>>> print(x)
item02
```

However, you might be doing this.

```
>>> x
'item02
```